# Is it possible for keycloak to filter users by custom attribute

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to create a UMS that uses the Keycloak's REST API. Some users will be `users` and some other `managers`. To differentiate them, they'll belong to different groups and they'll inherit a different set of roles.

All of the users will have a custom attribute named `locale`. What I'm trying to achieve on this point, is every time a manager tries to fetch the list of users using the REST API ex. `{{keycloak_url}}/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users` **only** users with the same custom attribute `locale` should return.

example:

Complete list of users:

```
USERNAME LOCALE
manager1 en
manager2 fr
user1    en
user2    en
user3    fr
```

`manager1` requests the users list expected result:

```
USERNAME LOCALE
manager1 en
user1    en
user2    en
```

`manager2` requests the users list expected result:

```
USERNAME LOCALE
manager2 fr
user3    fr
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this using Keycloak?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Keycloak does not provide such functionality because it is out of the scope of the SSO definition.

But you are free to implement a custom endpoint with filtering users by attribute `locale` taken from the manager's token.

You can find code here https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/domain-extension

[Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain it with https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/17.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource

putting "q" in the string, like this:

```
https://localhost/admin/realms/{realm}/users?q=locale:
```

This will return what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My initial question was about hitting the `{{keycloak_url}}/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users` api and filter by custom attribute on Keycloak's side without using the `q` parameter (mostly for security reasons).